# Trying to access array offset on value of type null...in login details

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

```
if ($row['email'] == $email && $row['password'] == $password) { 
  echo "Login success Welcome".$row['username']; # code... 
} 
else{ 
  echo "failed to login"; 
}
```

Comment: $row is null. You can not access any keys on null.

Comment: Go with `if( $row && $row['email']==$email && $row['password']==$password ) { ... };`

Comment: It means $row is null. So I guess you maybe need to review your logic, and work out what to do if the query returns no rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `if(!is_null($row))` along with the other checks, or simply:

```
if( $row && $row['email']==$email && $row['password']==$password ) { ... };
```

This happens when you query your DB, and there is no match, so there's no result, so the result is empty/null..  which you seem not to be checking within your code..